React Native Debugger Not Working in New React Native CLI Project (0.76.2)
I created a new React Native project using the CLI with version 0.76.2. However, I’m unable to get the React Native Debugger (RND) to work. It does not connect or behave as expected.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Installed and launched the React Native Debugger.
Confirmed it’s listening on the default port (8081).
Symptoms:
The debugger window opens but does not connect to the app.
Environment Details:
React Native version: 0.76.2 (new project created via CLI)
React Native Debugger version: v0.14.0
OS: (macOS Sequoia)
Node.js version: v20.15.0
React Native CLI: (installed globally or using npx)
What I’ve Tried:
Restarting the debugger and Metro bundler.
Clearing the cache with npm start --reset-cache.
Checking for port conflicts or network restrictions.
Ensuring no issues in the Metro server logs.
Since this is a brand-new project, I suspect there might be a configuration issue or compatibility problem with the debugger and this version of React Native.
What I Expect:
React Native Debugger should connect to the app, allowing me to view logs, inspect Redux states, and debug network requests.
Has anyone else faced this issue with a new project in version 0.76.2? Are there any specific steps or configurations needed to make the debugger work in this setup?
Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated!
